# Another "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function" for Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, return, syntax-error, jsonify

Im trying to get over this beginners rut and wanted to see what the community would suggest.

Photo #1
[CODE ON SPYDER IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9gVx.png)

Photo #2 [SyntaxError ON SPYDER CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcsL5.png)

The goal of this project is to relay the extracted data from an OBDII device to a flask application so the data can be displayed (using Postman to test script)

I'm having difficulty figuring out how my 'return' statement landed outside my function
and the fixes I need to do to move past this.

All help is deeply appreciated :)

```
import obd
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json

#Creating a Web App 
app = Flask(__name__)

#Extracting OBDII Data (RPM for now)
@app.route('/Extract_Data', methods=['GET'])

def Extract_Data():
    obd.logger.setLevel(obd.logging.DEBUG)
connection=obd.OBD()
rpm=obd.commands.RPM
response=connection.query(rpm)
connection.close()
return jsonify(response.value),200

#Running The App 
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

Comment: Why empty line between ```@app.route('/Extract_Data', methods=['GET'])``` and

```def Extract_Data():```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indent the code in your function. Python relies heavily on indentation, so you have to indent any code inside a function.

```py
import obd
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json

# Creating a Web App 
app = Flask(__name__)

# Extracting OBDII Data (RPM for now)
@app.route('/Extract_Data', methods=['GET'])
def Extract_Data():
    obd.logger.setLevel(obd.logging.DEBUG)
    connection=obd.OBD()
    rpm=obd.commands.RPM
    response=connection.query(rpm)
    connection.close()
    return jsonify(response.value), 200

# Running The App 
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

Also, on this line: `return jsonify(response.value), 200`, 200 is the default status code so you could use `return jsonify(response.value)` instead.